# Microsoft-Cognitive text translation works inaccurate

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the translator api of microsoft azure and it works inaccurate. 
In my example I translate form english to german:

[image]

[image]

The first picture shows correct translations except for "apple" which should be "Apfel" in german, also the second image shows another mistake as "pepino" is in German a "Birnenmelone", also dict.leo.org knows this.
Does anyone has an idea how to increase the accuracy of the service or how to change the input to get a better output?

**Update**: I thought also context count, so i simply used articles and also try to even give the context of "XYZ is a fruit". This made the results just a little better so that around 50% of the feedback is right now.

Answer (score 0):

The Translator API is not intended to be a dictionary lookup, but rather a translation of natural language where context can help determine the translation.  If you are just searching for a single word then the Translation API will generally return the most commonly used form of that word within the training data, which for "apple" would be the company Apple.

Alternatively, instead of calling the Translate API, you can call the GetTranslations API (or GetTranslationsArray) and pass in the optional `<options>` body with `<IncludeMultipleMTAlternatives>true</IncludeMultipleMTAlternatives>` to get multiple alternative translations.  This is documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn887253.aspx and we are working to get it into the Azure Cognitive Services documentation as well.

Example:

**REQUEST**

```
POST https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/GetTranslations?text=apple&from=en&to=de&maxTranslations=5 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler 
Authorization: Bearer xxx
Host: api.microsofttranslator.com
Content-Length: 325
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: text/xml

<TranslateOptions xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2"><Category>general</Category><ContentType>text/plain</ContentType><IncludeMultipleMTAlternatives>true</IncludeMultipleMTAlternatives><ReservedFlags></ReservedFlags><State></State><Uri></Uri><User>TestUserId</User></TranslateOptions>
```

**RESPONSE**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Length: 553 Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8 X-MS-Trans-Info: 0639.V2_Rest.GetTranslations.491248A8 Date: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 20:55:44 GMT

<GetTranslationsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><From>en</From><State/><Translations><TranslationMatch><Count>0</Count><MatchDegree>100</MatchDegree><MatchedOriginalText/><Rating>5</Rating><TranslatedText>Apple</TranslatedText></TranslationMatch><TranslationMatch><Count>0</Count><MatchDegree>100</MatchDegree><MatchedOriginalText/><Rating>0</Rating><TranslatedText>Apfel</TranslatedText></TranslationMatch></Translations></GetTranslationsResponse>
```